# adding list items into list in c#

Tags: c#

i have an list with data like this

```
name    |school |parent
--------+-------+-------
kumar   |fes    |TOP
manju   |fes    |kumar
anu     |frank  |kumar
anitha  |jss    |TOP
rohit   |frank  |manju
anill   |vijaya |manju
vani    |jss    |kumar
soumya  |jss    |kumar
madhu   |jss    |rohit
shiva   |jss    |rohit
vanitha |jss    |anitha
anu     |jss    |anitha
```

Code:

```
List<EMP> obj2 = new List<EMP>();
List<EMP> obj3 = new List<EMP>();
List<EMP> obj4 = new List<EMP>();

string [] strnames= {"Top","kumar","Anu","manju"};

//what i am  doing here is that in the string array i have the names of the string.
obj2 = ObjEmp.Where(p1 => p1.Parent == "Top").ToList();
obj3 = ObjEmp.Where(p1 => p1.Parent == "kumar").ToList();
obj4 = ObjEmp.Where(p1 => p1.Parent == "manju ").ToList();
```

here
**obj2 =  ObjEmp.Where(p1 => p1.Parent == "Top").ToList();**
here in obj2  will be  filled  with  data(kumar      fes         TOP,anitha      jss          TOP) with these  two data.

now row kumar has further data 
obj3 =ObjEmp.Where(p1 => p1.Parent == "kumar").ToList();

here wat get some more data.what we need to do here is that we need to take data  from

obj3  and then add  those  data in obj2[].  and  also  make  sure  that we  add the  obj3

data in obj2.

here as obj2  will be  filled  with datalike{obj2[0],obj2[1],obj2[2],obj2[3]}

here  we  again need  to check where under  which object  should we  place the data

hope my question is clear? 
 anyhelp would be great
 thanks

Comment: Looking at the last 3 questions you've asked they seem similar and all are quite difficult to understand. This one follows the same trend.

Comment: You "hope your question is clear", but I can't even find a question mark. What's the question?

Comment: can you edit your question and simplify it with some clarification

Comment: "hope my question is clear": no, I am afraid. Please start by reformatting your question to make it more readable. If you could provide a more concrete question in the same effort that would help as well.

Comment: Tried a little clean up. The code part was easy, but the text below is so hard to understand...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to build a tree out of your data.
There is not inbuilt collection type for trees, so you need to implement your own.  Dan Vanderboom shows how this could be done in his [blog](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/).

And no, your question is not clear. =)